# Is it possible to make anchors look like radio buttons or checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor, html-input

As in the title: I need an `a` tag that looks as if it was `<input type="radio">` or `<input type="checkbox">`.

I was thinking about achieving this by enclosing the `<input>` within the anchor (something like `<a href="blahblah"><input type="radio"></a>`, but sadly it seems that [HTML forbids this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#properties).

I was trying to search SO for similar questions and invariably the comments or answers were along the lines of "*Why do you want to do this, it makes no sense*". Expecting similar comments/answers under this question and fearing that I may have fallen for the XY problem let me show what led me here.

Suppose you have a webpage of this sort: (SPA to make it easier to embed in a fiddle):

```js
for(const input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
    input.onchange = () => {
        for(const inp of document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')) {
            const regularSection = document.querySelector(`#${inp.value}`)
            const bossSection = document.querySelector(`#${inp.value}Bosses`)
            if(inp.checked) {
                regularSection.classList.remove('hidden')
                if(document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked) {
                    bossSection.classList.remove('hidden')
                } else {
                    bossSection.classList.add('hidden')
                }
            } else {
                regularSection.classList.add('hidden')
                bossSection.classList.add('hidden')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    Show monsters from: <label><input type="radio" name="monsterArea" value="grassFields" checked>Grass Fields</label> <label><input type="radio" name="monsterArea" value="darkCave">Dark Cave</label> <label><input type="checkbox" checked>Include bosses</label>
</nav>

<section id="grassFields">
  <section>
  <h2>Galloping Stallion</h2>
  <p>Speed: 120</p>
  <p>Strength: 80</p>
  <p>HP: 500</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
  <h2>Shy Rabbit</h2>
  <p>Speed: 150</p>
  <p>Strength: 20</p>
  <p>HP: 100</p>
  </section>
</section>

<section id="grassFieldsBosses">
  <section>
  <h2>Fire Dragon</h2>
  <p>Speed: 130</p>
  <p>Strength: 250</p>
  <p>HP: 2500</p>
  </section>
</section>

<section id="darkCave" class="hidden">
  <section>
  <h2>Vampire Bat</h2>
  <p>Speed: 80</p>
  <p>Strength: 40</p>
  <p>HP: 100</p>
  </section>
</section>

<section id="darkCaveBosses" class="hidden">
  <section>
  <h2>Vampire Lord</h2>
  <p>Speed: 90</p>
  <p>Strength: 200</p>
  <p>HP: 1500</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

This works but it is suboptimal, people cannot (for example) bookmark a page that lists monsters from the Dark Cave.

To remedy this shortcomming we need to provide links to addresses, either leading to traditional subpages or, in SPA style, using History API. In case of traditional pages this would look something like this: (sorry, by necessity links are broken in a fiddle, but I hope the idea is still clear):

```js
for(const input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
    input.onchange = () => {
        const bosses = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked
        const area = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')).find(i => i.checked).value
        if(bosses) {
            window.location = `/${area}`
        } else {
            window.location = `/${area}Bosses`
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
    Show monsters from: <label><input type="radio" name="monsterArea" value="grassFields" checked>Grass Fields</label> <label><input type="radio" name="monsterArea" value="darkCave">Dark Cave</label> <label><input type="checkbox" checked>Include bosses</label>
</nav>

<section id="grassFields">
  <section>
  <h2>Galloping Stallion</h2>
  <p>Speed: 120</p>
  <p>Strength: 80</p>
  <p>HP: 500</p>
  </section>

  <section>
  <h2>Shy Rabbit</h2>
  <p>Speed: 150</p>
  <p>Strength: 20</p>
  <p>HP: 100</p>
  </section>
</section>

<section id="grassFieldsBosses">
  <section>
  <h2>Fire Dragon</h2>
  <p>Speed: 130</p>
  <p>Strength: 250</p>
  <p>HP: 2500</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

That's a bummer because [Google say they do not support such links and instead they require plain `<a href="/actual/address/not/JS#code">` links](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/links-crawlable). So I really need the `<a>` tag, *not* `input`s that work as if they were `<a>`s.

But, on the other hand, `<a>` tags won't have the same aesthetical feeling as my old `input`s. While I guess I could somehow get what I want by removing the radio buttons and replacing them with a bulleted list of `<a>` tags I have no idea what to do with the checkbox.

Is there any way to do what I want? Whether by making `<a>` tags work like anchors or, if I've badly fallen for the XY problem, in another way?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit lost. What do you actually want to happen when the user clicks one of the anchor elements? Is it different for 'radio' looking a elements and 'checkbox' looking ones?

Comment: @AHaworth Just like in my first snippet, relevant data should be shown.

Comment: simply use a SVG or a radio-button icon

Comment: You have a typo at window.locaiton = `/${area}Bosses` , must be window.location